# How to compare 2 schema files so that I can add the columns in the other file and fill with some default value?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have two files that have tabluar data. In file A, I have 5 columns and in file B I have 3 columns. I want to find the position of the columns in file A and add the new columns in file B. I also need to fill all the rows in file B with a default value that I will hard code.

I tried to run a loop to get the length of the files and then fetch the data but it's failing.

I'm using PuTTY and vim editor. Need to write a script to compare and add.

Comment: What do you mean "two files that have tabular data"? Are they csv files, tsv files, something different? Can you show the code you are using to try to combine them?

Answer (score 1):

Without having a concrete example of fileA and fileB it's difficult to figure out the right solution, but you could use diff and patch, something like this:

```
diff fileA fileB | patch -R fileB
```